# How can I use a function as a closure when the function needs to take a reference to the closures argument?

Tags: reference, rust, closures

The following code works (`cargo +nightly run`) fine:

```
fn main() {
    let res: Result<(), String> = Err(String::from("hi"));
    println!("{}", res.map_err(shout).unwrap_err())
}

fn shout(s: String) -> String {
    s.to_ascii_uppercase()
}
```

Clippy (`cargo +nightly clippy`) spits out a (justified) warning:

```
warning: this argument is passed by value, but not consumed in the function body
 --> src/main.rs:6:13
  |
6 | fn shout(s: String) -> String {
  |             ^^^^^^ help: consider changing the type to: `&str`
```

Changing the code to the suggested version

```
fn shout(s: &str) -> String {
    s.to_ascii_uppercase()
}
```

results in a compiler error:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
 --> src/main.rs:3:24
  |
3 |     println!("{}", res.map_err(shout).unwrap_err())
  |                        ^^^^^^^ expected signature of `fn(std::string::String) -> _`
...
6 | fn shout(s: &str) -> String {
  | --------------------------- found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r str) -> _`
```

What is the right way to react? Sure, I could simply do `#![cfg_attr(feature="clippy", allow(needless_pass_by_value))]` but this feels wrong to me. Is there a way to use `map_err` with the version of `shout` taking a reference?

Comment: Given your specific problem you could use [`String::make_ascii_uppercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html?search=#method.make_ascii_uppercase) to implement `shout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you can do is use a full closure:

```
res.map_err(|x| shout(&x)).unwrap_err()
```

Your original form has two steps needed to be able to work:

1. It needs to take the argument to the closure and convert it to a reference.
2. It needs to convert the `&String` to a `&str`.

Additionally, it needs to do both of those while the value is in scope, so that it doesn't end up with a dangling reference. Neither of these are things the "short" form of closures handles right now — the types must match exactly.

If you *really* wanted to avoid the closure, you can for this specific case:

```
res.as_ref().map_err(String::as_str).map_err(shout).unwrap_err()
//  ^~~~~~           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  |                |
//  |                |- Convert `&String` to `&str`
//  |   
//  |- Get a reference (`&String`)
```

I actually [argued for the ability for your original code to work](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/ergonomics-initiative-discussion-allowing-owned-values-where-references-are-expected/5161/2) as part of the ergonomics initiative, but it did not seem to gain traction.

---

Like many problems in programming, you can "solve" this by adding more abstraction. Here, we introduce a trait to embody the concept of "an error that can be shouted":

```
fn main() {
    let e1 = Err::<(), _>(String::from("hi"));
    println!("{}", e1.map_err(ShoutyError::shout).unwrap_err());

    let e2 = Err::<(), _>(42);
    println!("{}", e2.map_err(ShoutyError::shout).unwrap_err());
}

trait ShoutyError {
    fn shout(self) -> String;
}

impl ShoutyError for String {
    fn shout(self) -> String {
        self.to_ascii_uppercase()
    }
}

impl ShoutyError for i32 {
    fn shout(self) -> String {
        format!("I YELL {}", self)
    }
}
```

If you felt like you needed it, you could also have a wrapper function to keep the exact initial code:

```
fn shout<E: ShoutyError>(e: E) -> String {
    e.shout()
}
```

---

> I'd like to have a function `adapt` that takes one function `f : &T -> U` and returns a new function `g : T -> U`.

This is possible, but only in nightly Rust:

```
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait)]

fn adapt<F, T, U>(f: F) -> impl Fn(T) -> U
where
    F: Fn(&T) -> U,
{
    move |arg| f(&arg)
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't solve your problem because `shout` doesn't accept a `&String` and this would require `str` to be a `Sized` type.

The more verbose solution involves `AsRef`:

```
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait)]

fn adapt<F, T1, T2, U>(f: F) -> impl Fn(T1) -> U
where
    F: Fn(&T2) -> U,
    T1: AsRef<T2>,
    T2: ?Sized,
{
    move |arg| f(arg.as_ref())
}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I just upvoted your old post. ;) Yes, I would like to avoid the closure, but it's not always `String` in my code, but also `json::JsonValue` and `std::str::Utf8Error`, so `map_err(String::as_str)` does not solve all my cases. Is there a possibility to create a generic higher-order function one could use as an adapter, like `res.map_err(adapt(shout)).unwrap_err()`?

Comment: @TobiasHermann I'm not sure I'm following you. You'd like a function that takes both a `json::JsonValue` and a `std::str::Utf8Error`, converts them to a reference (to what, exactly? a `&str`?) and then passes that to `shout`?

Comment: Sorry, the `shout` function was just an example.

I'd like to have a function `adapt` that takes one function `f : &T -> U` and returns a new function `g : T -> U`. So `adapt : (&T -> U) -> (T -> U)`. This way we could solve [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9a8196c1a8a8b779992d4ad8d0b38456&version=stable) by doing something like [that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=601d74d350d55d21bcaff57b7190d510&version=stable).

Comment: Nice, thanks. After [implementing some traits](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5c799344eeaa6259ed2f7f2626b33a8a&version=nightly), is really works. However since this is for production code, I would like to use `stable`, and thus will go with the [closure solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2a98f75adc5ad567a2938ba8d8947536&version=stable).